# Error when running Java code with dalvikvm

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, dalvik

I have a RunTest.dex file that I have created from Java source code, and I'm trying to run it on my android device (Galaxy S4) using "dalvikvm -cp RunTest.dex Runtest".  My issue is that my program makes a jni call to a shared library, but the linker cannot find my shared library even though it is in the same directory as my .dex file.  I created the shared library with ndk-build, so I know that it has been built correctly.

Error message from console:

```
shell@jfltevzw:/sdcard/Download $ dalvikvm -cp RunTest.dex RunTest             
Unable to find static main(String[]) in 'RunTest'
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load eitTest from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=RunTest.dex,libraryPath=null]: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
    at RunTest.<clinit>(RunTest.java:5)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load eitTest from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=RunTest.dex,libraryPath=null]: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
    at RunTest.<clinit>(RunTest.java:5)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Java Source code:

```
class RunTest{
    native void eitTest();

    static{
        System.loadLibrary("eitTest");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        RunTest runTest = new RunTest();
        runTest.eitTest();
    }
}
```

Native Code:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_RunTest_eitTest(JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj){
    printf("Hello From C!!!\n");
  }
```

I have also set "ANDROID_DATA=/sdcard/Download", where I have a dalvik-cache folder.

Comment: You probably want to use System.load() which takes the full absolute path and filename of wherever you actually put the .so instead of loadLibrary() which searches configured paths for a library matching naming conventions.  However, at least on an ARM device the .so must be executable and not on a volume mounted no-exec, so don't put it on the external storage.

Comment: I believe /data/local/tmp should be accessible by the shell user, and should allow you to set the executable bit.

Comment: Thanks guys, all those tips were what I needed!!